# How to hide a div while scrolling using pure JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I have a div that covers my whole web page. Beneath it I also have a set of divs. I want to be able to hide my div while scrolling down so my other divs beneath it can start appearing.

the div for now is colored in black with an absolute position. I want this div to be the first page the user sees and then it starts hiding when the user scrolls down and the other divs beneath it to appear.

Here is my html:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #201e2f;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-indent: 30px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#parentContainer {
  background-color: #ffc107;
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
}

#courseImage {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

#courseDescription {
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  float: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #201e2f;
  margin: 15px;
  border: 0;
  color: #ffc107;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: right;
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  font-size: 15px;
}

img {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 500px 500px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.class1 {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.class2 {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.class6 {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.class5 {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

#toHide {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="toHide">
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="parentContainer" class="class1">
    <div id="courseImage">
      <img src="wd.png" alt="Sorry, couldn't load image">
    </div>

    <div id="courseDescription">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum, lacus vel commodo semper, nisi elit ultricies lacus, in interdum massa mi at nisl. Praesent sit amet commodo nunc, sit amet mattis dui. Cras sodales sit amet velit sed tristique.
      </p>

      <button id="startButton">Start Learning!</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="parentContainer" class="class2">
    <div id="courseImage">
      <img src="wd.png" alt="Sorry, couldn't load image">
    </div>

    <div id="courseDescription">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum, lacus vel commodo semper, nisi elit ultricies lacus, in interdum massa mi at nisl. Praesent sit amet commodo nunc, sit amet mattis dui. Cras sodales sit amet velit sed tristique.
      </p>

      <button id="startButton">
                                Start Learning!
                            </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="parentContainer">
    <div id="courseImage">
      <img src="wd.png" alt="Sorry, couldn't load image">
    </div>

    <div id="courseDescription">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum, lacus vel commodo semper, nisi elit ultricies lacus, in interdum massa mi at nisl. Praesent sit amet commodo nunc, sit amet mattis dui. Cras sodales sit amet velit sed tristique.
      </p>

      <button id="startButton">
                                Start Learning!
                            </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="parentContainer">
    <div id="courseImage">
      <img src="wd.png" alt="Sorry, couldn't load image">
    </div>

    <div id="courseDescription">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum, lacus vel commodo semper, nisi elit ultricies lacus, in interdum massa mi at nisl. Praesent sit amet commodo nunc, sit amet mattis dui. Cras sodales sit amet velit sed tristique.
      </p>

      <button id="startButton">
                                Start Learning!
                            </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="parentContainer" class="class5">
    <div id="courseImage">
      <img src="wd.png" alt="Sorry, couldn't load image">
    </div>

    <div id="courseDescription">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum, lacus vel commodo semper, nisi elit ultricies lacus, in interdum massa mi at nisl. Praesent sit amet commodo nunc, sit amet mattis dui. Cras sodales sit amet velit sed tristique.
      </p>

      <button id="startButton">
                                    Start Learning!
                                </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="parentContainer" class="class6">
    <div id="courseImage">
      <img src="wd.png" alt="Sorry, couldn't load image">
    </div>

    <div id="courseDescription">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum, lacus vel commodo semper, nisi elit ultricies lacus, in interdum massa mi at nisl. Praesent sit amet commodo nunc, sit amet mattis dui. Cras sodales sit amet velit sed tristique.
      </p>

      <button id="startButton">
                                    Start Learning!
                                </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

how can I do that with pure JS or CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by modifying the `opacity` property of the div once the user begins to scroll. Also, here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/XyZjmJ) and a reference for [`onscroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll) :)

```js
// listen for a scroll event in the window containing the DOM
window.onscroll = ()=>{
  // grab the div we want to hide
  let toHide = document.getElementById('toHide');
  // fade the div above out by setting its opacity to 0
  toHide.style.opacity = 0;
}
```

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #201e2f;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-indent: 30px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#parentContainer {
  background-color: #ffc107;
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
}

#courseImage {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

#courseDescription {
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  float: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #201e2f;
  margin: 15px;
  border: 0;
  color: #ffc107;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: right;
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  font-size: 15px;
}

img {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 500px 500px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.class1 {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.class2 {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.class6 {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.class5 {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

#toHide {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="toHide">
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="parentContainer" class="class1">
      <div id="courseImage">
        <img src="wd.png" alt="Sorry, couldn't load image">
      </div>

      <div id="courseDescription">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum, lacus vel commodo semper, nisi elit ultricies lacus, in interdum massa mi at nisl. Praesent sit amet commodo nunc, sit amet mattis dui. Cras sodales sit amet velit sed tristique.
        </p>

        <button id="startButton">
                        Start Learning!
                    </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="parentContainer" class="class2">
      <div id="courseImage">
        <img src="wd.png" alt="Sorry, couldn't load image">
      </div>

      <div id="courseDescription">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum, lacus vel commodo semper, nisi elit ultricies lacus, in interdum massa mi at nisl. Praesent sit amet commodo nunc, sit amet mattis dui. Cras sodales sit amet velit sed tristique.
        </p>

        <button id="startButton">
                            Start Learning!
                        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="parentContainer">
      <div id="courseImage">
        <img src="wd.png" alt="Sorry, couldn't load image">
      </div>

      <div id="courseDescription">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum, lacus vel commodo semper, nisi elit ultricies lacus, in interdum massa mi at nisl. Praesent sit amet commodo nunc, sit amet mattis dui. Cras sodales sit amet velit sed tristique.
        </p>

        <button id="startButton">
                            Start Learning!
                        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="parentContainer">
      <div id="courseImage">
        <img src="wd.png" alt="Sorry, couldn't load image">
      </div>

      <div id="courseDescription">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum, lacus vel commodo semper, nisi elit ultricies lacus, in interdum massa mi at nisl. Praesent sit amet commodo nunc, sit amet mattis dui. Cras sodales sit amet velit sed tristique.
        </p>

        <button id="startButton">
                            Start Learning!
                        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="parentContainer" class="class5">
      <div id="courseImage">
        <img src="wd.png" alt="Sorry, couldn't load image">
      </div>

      <div id="courseDescription">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum, lacus vel commodo semper, nisi elit ultricies lacus, in interdum massa mi at nisl. Praesent sit amet commodo nunc, sit amet mattis dui. Cras sodales sit amet velit sed tristique.
        </p>

        <button id="startButton">
                                Start Learning!
                            </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="parentContainer" class="class6">
      <div id="courseImage">
        <img src="wd.png" alt="Sorry, couldn't load image">
      </div>

      <div id="courseDescription">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum, lacus vel commodo semper, nisi elit ultricies lacus, in interdum massa mi at nisl. Praesent sit amet commodo nunc, sit amet mattis dui. Cras sodales sit amet velit sed tristique.
        </p>

        <button id="startButton">
                                Start Learning!
                            </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

On the other hand, since you mentioned you want the div to be the first thing your users see when your page loads, you can do something like this so it'll reappear when the user scrolls back up to the top again:

```js
// listen for a scroll event in the window containing the DOM
window.onscroll = ()=>{
  // grab the div we want to hide
  let toHide = document.getElementById('toHide');
  // fade the div above out by setting its opacity to 0
  // if the user scrolled down, scrollY will be greater than 0
  if(window.scrollY > 0){
    toHide.classList.add('hide');
  }
  else{
    toHide.classList.remove('hide');
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #201e2f;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-indent: 30px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#parentContainer {
  background-color: #ffc107;
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
}

#courseImage {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

#courseDescription {
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  float: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #201e2f;
  margin: 15px;
  border: 0;
  color: #ffc107;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: right;
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  font-size: 15px;
}

img {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 500px 500px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.class1 {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.class2 {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.class6 {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.class5 {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

#toHide {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="toHide">
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="parentContainer" class="class1">
      <div id="courseImage">
        <img src="wd.png" alt="Sorry, couldn't load image">
      </div>

      <div id="courseDescription">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum, lacus vel commodo semper, nisi elit ultricies lacus, in interdum massa mi at nisl. Praesent sit amet commodo nunc, sit amet mattis dui. Cras sodales sit amet velit sed tristique.
        </p>

        <button id="startButton">
                        Start Learning!
                    </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="parentContainer" class="class2">
      <div id="courseImage">
        <img src="wd.png" alt="Sorry, couldn't load image">
      </div>

      <div id="courseDescription">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum, lacus vel commodo semper, nisi elit ultricies lacus, in interdum massa mi at nisl. Praesent sit amet commodo nunc, sit amet mattis dui. Cras sodales sit amet velit sed tristique.
        </p>

        <button id="startButton">
                            Start Learning!
                        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="parentContainer">
      <div id="courseImage">
        <img src="wd.png" alt="Sorry, couldn't load image">
      </div>

      <div id="courseDescription">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum, lacus vel commodo semper, nisi elit ultricies lacus, in interdum massa mi at nisl. Praesent sit amet commodo nunc, sit amet mattis dui. Cras sodales sit amet velit sed tristique.
        </p>

        <button id="startButton">
                            Start Learning!
                        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="parentContainer">
      <div id="courseImage">
        <img src="wd.png" alt="Sorry, couldn't load image">
      </div>

      <div id="courseDescription">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum, lacus vel commodo semper, nisi elit ultricies lacus, in interdum massa mi at nisl. Praesent sit amet commodo nunc, sit amet mattis dui. Cras sodales sit amet velit sed tristique.
        </p>

        <button id="startButton">
                            Start Learning!
                        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="parentContainer" class="class5">
      <div id="courseImage">
        <img src="wd.png" alt="Sorry, couldn't load image">
      </div>

      <div id="courseDescription">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum, lacus vel commodo semper, nisi elit ultricies lacus, in interdum massa mi at nisl. Praesent sit amet commodo nunc, sit amet mattis dui. Cras sodales sit amet velit sed tristique.
        </p>

        <button id="startButton">
                                Start Learning!
                            </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="parentContainer" class="class6">
      <div id="courseImage">
        <img src="wd.png" alt="Sorry, couldn't load image">
      </div>

      <div id="courseDescription">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum, lacus vel commodo semper, nisi elit ultricies lacus, in interdum massa mi at nisl. Praesent sit amet commodo nunc, sit amet mattis dui. Cras sodales sit amet velit sed tristique.
        </p>

        <button id="startButton">
                                Start Learning!
                            </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/PxQGML) for the snippet above and a reference to [`scrollY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY).

The second example also makes use of a css class (`.hide`) instead of modifying the involved property using solely pure JS. The class is dynamically added and removed using the `addClass` and `removeClass` methods of the toHide div's[`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest applying a scroll listener putting a CSS class on your overlay div that causes a fade transition:

```js
document.addEventListener('scroll', () => { toHide.classList.add('hiddenByScroll')});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #201e2f;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-indent: 30px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#parentContainer {
  background-color: #ffc107;
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
}

#courseImage {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

#courseDescription {
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  float: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #201e2f;
  margin: 15px;
  border: 0;
  color: #ffc107;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: right;
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  font-size: 15px;
}

img {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 500px 500px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.class1 {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.class2 {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.class6 {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.class5 {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

#toHide {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

#toHide.hiddenByScroll {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="toHide">
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="parentContainer" class="class1">
    <div id="courseImage">
      <img src="wd.png" alt="Sorry, couldn't load image">
    </div>

    <div id="courseDescription">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum, lacus vel commodo semper, nisi elit ultricies lacus, in interdum massa mi at nisl. Praesent sit amet commodo nunc, sit amet mattis dui. Cras sodales sit amet velit sed tristique.
      </p>

      <button id="startButton">Start Learning!</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="parentContainer" class="class2">
    <div id="courseImage">
      <img src="wd.png" alt="Sorry, couldn't load image">
    </div>

    <div id="courseDescription">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum, lacus vel commodo semper, nisi elit ultricies lacus, in interdum massa mi at nisl. Praesent sit amet commodo nunc, sit amet mattis dui. Cras sodales sit amet velit sed tristique.
      </p>

      <button id="startButton">
                                Start Learning!
                            </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="parentContainer">
    <div id="courseImage">
      <img src="wd.png" alt="Sorry, couldn't load image">
    </div>

    <div id="courseDescription">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum, lacus vel commodo semper, nisi elit ultricies lacus, in interdum massa mi at nisl. Praesent sit amet commodo nunc, sit amet mattis dui. Cras sodales sit amet velit sed tristique.
      </p>

      <button id="startButton">
                                Start Learning!
                            </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="parentContainer">
    <div id="courseImage">
      <img src="wd.png" alt="Sorry, couldn't load image">
    </div>

    <div id="courseDescription">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum, lacus vel commodo semper, nisi elit ultricies lacus, in interdum massa mi at nisl. Praesent sit amet commodo nunc, sit amet mattis dui. Cras sodales sit amet velit sed tristique.
      </p>

      <button id="startButton">
                                Start Learning!
                            </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="parentContainer" class="class5">
    <div id="courseImage">
      <img src="wd.png" alt="Sorry, couldn't load image">
    </div>

    <div id="courseDescription">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum, lacus vel commodo semper, nisi elit ultricies lacus, in interdum massa mi at nisl. Praesent sit amet commodo nunc, sit amet mattis dui. Cras sodales sit amet velit sed tristique.
      </p>

      <button id="startButton">
                                    Start Learning!
                                </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="parentContainer" class="class6">
    <div id="courseImage">
      <img src="wd.png" alt="Sorry, couldn't load image">
    </div>

    <div id="courseDescription">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum, lacus vel commodo semper, nisi elit ultricies lacus, in interdum massa mi at nisl. Praesent sit amet commodo nunc, sit amet mattis dui. Cras sodales sit amet velit sed tristique.
      </p>

      <button id="startButton">
                                    Start Learning!
                                </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Make sure to also apply `pointer-events: none;`, otherwise the element will be invisible, but cannot be "clicked through" as it is still there.